# Rails Restful convention for records found by user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Say I have a cart that I find based on a current user record. How would a restful URI look for that.

You could say:
    PUT /carts/56/cart_items/67 For an Update example

However changing this URL would not effect the program as the controller most likely has something like

```
@cart = current_user.cart
```

Ideally the URL would look more like:
    PUT /user_cart/cart_items/67

Is there a rails router convention to build a system like this short of a bunch of custom routes?

Comment: I always wondered if do not specify a resource because of session data is ok for rest; I think it is because rest just says how to map resources and how to use HTTP verbs, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: I know you can get that done in `config/routes.rb` with the `:path` parameter in a resource, not sure if it's idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
namespace :checkout do
  resources :cart_items
  resources :carts
end
```

Even though cart_itmes are an embedded resource of carts their scope isn't part of the URI so the route is under a checkout namespace which makes since... kind of. Lol programming philosophy.